# PHP upload file error

Tags: php

I trying to upload a photo to my server using PHP but the script always goes to the else statement and I can not work out why.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$image=($_FILES['image']['name']);
$target = "../../portfolio/photos";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name'], $target))
{
    $sql_addProduct = "INSERT INTO photos (img_url) VALUES '$image'";
    $queryresult_add = mysql_query($sql_addProduct);

    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['image']['name']). " has been uploaded succesfully";
}
else {
    //Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Comment: Did you try to validate the `$_FILES` first?

Comment: Read the Docs: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) - this section of the manual has all information you need for your code as well as examples and user-comments with useful hints.

Comment: BTW: If you fixed your file issue, protect your database against SQL-Injection via the uploaded file-name.

Answer (score 4):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name']
```

should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: Correct! move_uploaded_file returns false if the filename is not valid.

Comment: In other words: `['name']` is the filename as provided by the client. `['tmp_name']` is the temporary file that PHP stored the upload in, and is what you need to use as the 'source' for the move command.

Comment: I have replaced 'name' with 'tmp_name' and now receive this error

Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../robyn/photos/imagetest.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or director

Answer (score 0):

Check `$_FILES["image"]["error"]` if file is correctly uploaded.
Then it may be useful (and more secure) to check if it is image with `getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);`. Then you can move it with 
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target);`
If it still not working, check if directory is writtable `is_writable($target);`